# How to add elements in an array as properties of an object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Let say I have an array:

```
var members = ["Peter", "Paul", "Mary"];
```

And an object:

```
var band = {};
```

Is there a way to iterate through the array such that each element in the members array will be added as properties of the band object with values as objects as well?

```
band = {"Peter": {}, "Paul": {}, "Mary": {} }
```

Comment: In a loop: `band[members[n]] = {};`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
var members = ["Peter", "Paul", "Mary"];
var band = {};

members.forEach(function(member) {
    band[member] = {};
});
```